# Getting errors with wxWidgets2.9.3 on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, ubuntu, wxwidgets, assert

I have installed wxWidgets 2.9.3 on Ubuntu 10.10 using
`../configure --with-gtk`
I am using Codeblocks IDE, and ran a sample Dialogs program easily on it.

But when I tried to run my working code on Windows, VS2010 (wxWidgets 2.9.2), I am getting several errors, and runtime failure, listed below

1. `error: ‘class wxBitmap’ has no member named ‘UseAlpha’`
2. `error: ‘class wxPanel’ has no member named ‘SetBackgroundBitmap’`
3. Following code, also raises error `assert "m_menuItem" failed in Enable(): invalid menu item`

   > ```
   > wxMenuItem *undoMenuItem;
   > wxMenu* editMenu = new wxMenu(_(""));
   > undoMenuItem = new wxMenuItem(editMenu, idMenuUndo, _("&Undo\tCtrl+Z"), _("Undo the last action"));
   > undoMenuItem->Enable(false);
   > editMenu->Append(undoMenuItem);
   > ```
4. If I comment out above code, compile and run, I get `SIGSEGV` and the call stack is

> 0 0x168f07a   cairo_save() (/usr/lib/libcairo.so.2:??)
>   1 0x806520    wxCairoContext::PushState() () (/usr/local/lib/libwx_gtk2u_core-2.9.so.3:??)
>   2 0x805b38    wxCairoContext::Init(_cairo*) () (/usr/local/lib/libwx_gtk2u_core-2.9.so.3:??)
>   3 0x80736a    wxCairoContext::wxCairoContext(wxGraphicsRenderer*, wxMemoryDC const&) () (/usr/local/lib/libwx_gtk2u_core-2.9.so.3:??)
>   4 0x807401    wxCairoRenderer::CreateContext(wxMemoryDC const&) () (/usr/local/lib/libwx_gtk2u_core-2.9.so.3:??)
>   5 0x822f06    wxGraphicsContext::Create(wxMemoryDC const&) () (/usr/local/lib/libwx_gtk2u_core-2.9.so.3:??)
>   6 0x7c54b7    wxGCDCImpl::wxGCDCImpl(wxDC*, wxMemoryDC const&) () (/usr/local/lib/libwx_gtk2u_core-2.9.so.3:??)
>   7 0x7c554e    wxGCDC::wxGCDC(wxMemoryDC const&) () (/usr/local/lib/libwx_gtk2u_core-2.9.so.3:??)
>   8 0x80555fd   Breadboard::reset(this=0x81713c0) (/home/vinayak/codes/IConBread/breadboard.cpp:79)
>   9 0x8054e57   Breadboard::Breadboard(this=0x81713c0) (/home/vinayak/codes/IConBread/breadboard.cpp:17)
>   10 0x805d7c5  Interface::Interface(this=0x8171200, parent=0x81703e0, width=900, height=570) (/home/vinayak/codes/IConBread/interface.cpp:24)
>   11 0x8069db4  MainFrame::MainFrame(this=0x8108af8, frame=0x0, title=...) (/home/vinayak/codes/IConBread/mainframe.cpp:127)
>   12 0x80525a8  Application::OnInit(this=0x80ab228) (/home/vinayak/codes/IConBread/application.cpp:27)
>   13 0x8053194  wxAppConsoleBase::CallOnInit(this=0x80ab228) (/usr/local/include/wx-2.9/wx/app.h:94)
>   14 0xc53000   wxEntry(int&, wchar_t**) () (/usr/local/lib/libwx_baseu-2.9.so.3:??)
>   15 0xc530d7   wxEntry(int&, char**) () (/usr/local/lib/libwx_baseu-2.9.so.3:??)
>   16 0x805245f  main(argc=1, argv=0xbffff924) (/home/vinayak/codes/IConBread/application.cpp:19)

What can be the possible cause of these errors? Remember, on windows (VS2010) this is a perfectly working code.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved above problems, with help from wxWidgets developers.

1. `UseAlpha` is MSW specific, so I can't use it on Linux
2. docs/changes.txt suggest
   `wxPanel::SetBackgroundBitmap()` was removed, derive your class from
   `wxCustomBackgroundWindow` and use its method with the same name instead.
3. Appending the item to the menu first, before disabling it, solves the issue.
4. This issue's solution has raised more issues, but runtime error is gone.
   I got over the runtime fault, by calling,
   `bitmap.Create(kWidth, kHeight, 32);`
   before the function which was accessing bitmap object. This line was being called after `bitmap` was being used, reordering lines solved the problem. 
   However I am unable to get transparency with `wxGCDC` now.